# How to port changes to higher version Kernel?

Tags: git, linux-kernel, migration

We are facing a porting task.
Currently we are using the Kernel which is offered by Qualcomm (3.18.20), and now Qualcomm has upgraded to new baseline. In the new baseline, Kernel has been upgraded to 3.18.48, which includes lots of Qualcomm changes.
We need to port our own changes(hundreds commits) to the new Qualcomm Kernel (3.18.48). 
Is there any standard or fast GIT method to port our own changes to Qualcomm new Kernel?

Thanks

Comment: Create them as patches. Apply the patches. Then fight with each patch that fails :-P Check out `git format-patch`

Comment: You can try `git rebase`, but I'd recommend creating a backup branch for your existing changes first, so you can go back to it easily.